# How to provide props.history push as a function's argument

Tags: reactjs, function, react-router

I have the following function which I use in two components:

```
export const removeItem = (id, cb) => {
  try {
    const remove = async () => {
      await axios.delete(`http://localhost:9000/news/${id}`);
      cb();
    };
    remove();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Im my NewsItemPage component I want to provide props.history.push('/news') as the second argument, but this code would not work:

```
<button onClick={() => {removeItem(someId, props.history.push('/news')) }}>remove</button>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a function around it to be able to use as callback.

like this `<button onClick={() => {removeItem(someId, () => {props.history.push('/news')}) }}>remove</button>`